# setAttribute and removeAttribute doesn't work in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript

setAttribute and removeAttribute doesn't work with chrome and firefox works only in IE.

below code is works fine in IE, doesn't work with any other exploerer

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function showUser2()
 {
   buttonpassvalue1.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
   buttonpassvalue.removeAttribute("disabled");
 }
 </script>
 </head>

  <button class="button" type="button" name="buttonpassvalue1" value="1" onclick="showUser2(this.value)">This will Disbale</button>
  <button class="button" type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="-1" onclick="showUser2(this.value)">Press This</button>
```

its terminates when reach to above code

thanks for your help

Comment: Post a complete example.

Comment: `setAttribute` is undefined for me in IE8. What type of object is `buttonpassvalue` and `buttonpassvalue1`?

Comment: @Blender i change the code above please try it in IE,Chrome,Opera, Mac, Firefox.....this works only in IE

Comment: It seems you didn't even do some basic debugging. The Chrome console shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: buttonpassvalue1 is not defined`. Instead of relying on the browser to create global variables for elements, use `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByName` to get references to the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit complicated to explain *why* your code doesn't work in other browsers. It has something to do with how the "disabled" attribute is treated, as there are different kinds of internal nodes and containers.

However, this doesn't prevent you from achieving what you're doing:

```
if(val123 > gotnumber){
   buttonpassvalue1.disabled='disabled';
   buttonpassvalue.disabled='';

}    else{
   buttonpassvalue.disabled='disabled';
   buttonpassvalue1.disabled='';
}
```

The "checked" attribute in checkboxes, and "readonly" in input fields work the same way.

Edit:

You have to give the elements IDs so you can grab them properly:

```
var buttonpassvalue=document.getElementById('buttonpassvalue');
var buttonpassvalue2=document.getElementById('buttonpassvalue2');
```

Edit again, with formatted and corrected code to disable the first button:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function showUser2(v){

   var buttonpassvalue1=document.getElementById('buttonpassvalue1');
   var buttonpassvalue2=document.getElementById('buttonpassvalue1');


   buttonpassvalue1.disabled='disabled';
   buttonpassvalue.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
 </script>
 </head>

  <button id="buttonpassvalue1" class="button" type="button" name="buttonpassvalue1" value="1" onclick="showUser2(this.value);">This will Disbale</button>
  <button id="buttonpassvalue" class="button" type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="-1" onclick="showUser2(this.value)">Press This</button>
```

Comment: If you use properties, you should use the values `true` and `false` instead.

Comment: Yes, except that for readonly, checked and disabled, they're not proper boolean values. It's a common mistake that people set them to "false", just to find out that the checkboxes are still checked.

Comment: @Schien no luck...please check my recent code up in question and try it in IE and others

Comment: @Schien: That is the case for the *HTML attributes* but not for the equivalent *DOM properties* (what you are using). As you can see in the HTML DOM spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025), `disabled` is a boolean property. You are right, `ele.setAttribute('disabled', false)` does not work as expected, but `ele.disabled = false` does.

Comment: Aha. This is a button, and button doesn't have a "value" property. Sure you can add one, but in IE, it'll ready the innerText of the button as its value. So your passed in values are incorrect.

Comment: @FashFootwear please try the formatted code in my edited answer and see if the first button is working in IE now. If so, then you'll have to pass in values explicitly. i.e. 1, 2, instead of this.value. this.value is not passed correctly on IE for reasons mentioned in my last comment

Answer (score 0):

In browsers conforming to the W3C DOM specifications, the *disabled* attribute sets whether an element is disabled **by default**, it does not set its current state. IE does not follow that model and setting the *disabled* attribute also sets the current state.

The *disabled* DOM property should be used to set the current state of an element:

```
buttonpassvalue1.disabled = true; // disabled

buttonpassvalue.disabled = false; // not disabled
```

There are many differences between browsers in how HTML attributes and DOM properties are implemented. The simple fix is to try to always use properties and only use attributes where they are explicitly required (which is very rarely).

Also, you are using element names as global variables. That is a bad idea and is a hangover from many years ago (though all browsers support it to some extent, just don't do it). Consider instead:

```
<script>
function disableElement(el) {
  el.disabled = true;
}
function enableElement(el) {
  el.disabled = false;
}
</script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="i0"><br>
  <button onclick="disableElement(this.form.i0)">Disable the input</button>
  <button onclick="enableElement(this.form.i0)">Enable the input</button>
</form>
```